# How to add billing permission V3 to expo managed app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I added "permission":["com.android.vending.BILLING"] in app.json.

but google gives error that I should use Billing version 3 but I can't found how to do so in expo managed app.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use:

```
expo build:android
```

command to build your app.

But after you ejected the app from Expo **managed** workflow into **bare** workflow, you must execute:

```
eas build --platform=android --profile=production
```

instead.

I just figured out this on my own prject, had fully the same error.

Comment: What to do if a user doesn't want to eject? No way to use billing on managed workflow?